# Passing STDIN to Binary from Script Causing Repeated Enters

Tags: c, linux, bash, process, stdin

I have a program that implements a command prompt menu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char username[32] = {0};
  printf("Username: ");
  fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
  username[strcspn(username, "\n")] = '\0';

  char password[32] = {0};
  printf("Password: ");
  fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
  password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = '\0';

  printf("\nWelcome!\n");

  while (1)
  {
    char command_buffer[1024] = {0};

    printf("Enter one of the following commands (EDG, UED, SCS, DTE, AED, UVF, OUT): ");
    fgets(command_buffer, sizeof(command_buffer), stdin);
    // fgets() is returning NULL and not blocking
    // as pointed out by @Spikatrix, probably because standard input stream was closed?
    command_buffer[strcspn(command_buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I want to pass in the username and password automatically, I have tried each of these options and both have not worked:

```
# username = "dev", password = "pass"

# Option1 
{ echo "dev" & sleep 0.1; echo "pass"; } | ./example

# Option2
./example <<< $'dev\npass\n'

# Option3
(echo "dev\npass" | cat) | ./example
```

After running the script, the `example` binary processes the username and password correctly (as you are advanced to the menu screen).
However, it just continually prints out the menu prompt `Enter one of the following commands (EDG, UED, SCS, DTE, AED, UVF, OUT):` . This to me suggests that a newline character (or something to a similar effect) is continuously being fed to the program.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], with emphasis on "minimal" and "complete".

Comment: You are writing an endless loop, which you never breaking out from, and now you are seriously asking why this loop never terminates??? Or did I misunderstand you? Also, as _busybee_ said, please post a **minimal** complete example.

Comment: @user1934428 `fgets()` blocks until data is available

Comment: `fgets` is probably returning `NULL` as the standard input stream gets closed after the input. Try `(echo "dev\npass" | cat) | ./client 127.0.0.1 8000 1234`

Comment: @Spikatrix I think you are correct, `fgets()` is returning `NULL`. Unfortunately your command does not work

Comment: @thebusybee Obliged

Comment: This is why you don't write `while(1)`.  Instead, you write `while( fgets(...) != NULL ...`. If you want to print a prompt (you really don't, but that's a different discussion), you can do `while( printf(....), fgets(...) != NULL )`

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` returns `NULL`, if the stream is closed, and does not block. This is the case with your redirection.

Since your program does not check the return value, it happily continues.